# How to dynamicaly load data from websites in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm learning iOS developing and want to make a news app that loads posts from different websites and merge it into one table. What is the code for    UITableViewCell to show like the image below:

[image]

Comment: if you want to do an example then you can try google news rss feed. It will give you news from different publishers.

Comment: You want scrapping of website?

Comment: if you want to know how you will get this then there is one example for that which you can get it from http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: One More for you which may help you is AFNetworking, Download framework and take a look on example of it which you will get from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

You will get many 3rd party API's which provide recent news, you can use any one of them, parse data and follow example below

This is an example using native UITableViewCell, you can use custom cell if you need your custom layout

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    NSDictionary *parsedData = self.loader.parsedData[indexPath.row];
    if (parsedData)
    {
       cell.imageView.image = nil;
       dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
       dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:parsedData[@"imageLR"]];

        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        if (image) {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
                     cell.imageView.image = image;
                     [cell setNeedsLayout];
                 }
             });
         }
         });

    cell.textLabel.text = parsedData[@"description"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What about Height of tableViewCell how they will adjust according to image size or text length ? The code you have done is for lazy loading images not for dynamically load tableview cell

Comment: Thanks , do u know how to load data from websites like buzzfeed.com or newyorktimes.com , some particular URL would only show one post but i want to show all the new posts